# Getting error in modification of models.IntegerField to models.ForeignKey im model ,Using Django's double underscore convention

Tags: python, django, view, django-models

```
raise TypeError('Related Field got invalid lookup: %s' % lookup_type)
TypeError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

If  I am modifying  `models.IntegerField` to `models.ForeignKey` in the model (Django/python) and corresponding table column then why am I  getting an error related to I contains, in spite of using Django's double underscore convention ?

Comment: Show us your models.py file and some code with error traceback,then We can help you in a better way.

Comment: Are you getting this error in admin panel? If yes, then I think the source is error is this: **You cannot filter a foreign key directly**.  You filter on some field of the Foreign Key model. Eg: `foreignkey__fkfieldname`. Please add some more relevant code, especially from `models.py` and `admin.py`.

Answer (score 0):

iexact or icontainsn is used where you match the lower and upper case alphabets.
For integers they dont have lower or upper case integers. So, you should go with contains except of icontains.

Comment: For foreign key you cannot use contains. you should do it like this

Comment: activity = Activity.objects.filter(objectWithForeignKeyName__in = [1])